# how can I Add xhtml Wizard in eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create Xhtml page in dynamic web project. Thanks for help. I tried to install jboss web tools but it doesn't work.

Comment: What specific problem did you encounter with JBoss Web Tools?

Comment: Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: I want when i select a new wizard on the web content, i can find xhtml page. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need the **Java EE Devleoper Tools** to create  **Dynamic Web Projects**. Then, you can install the **[Web Tools Platform (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)** plugin to provide the `xhtml` functionality that you are seeking.

The following is the simplest way to install those tools:

- Go to `Help->Install New Software`.
- In the dropdown, select 'Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno'
- Expand 'Web, XML, Java EE, and OSGI Enterprise Development'
- Check the box for 'Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools' and '**[Web Tools Platform (WTP)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)**'